# Create local database in unity3d

Tags: database, unity-game-engine

I'm planing to develop a game in Unity3D. I didn't choose yed if it will be in javascript, c# script or boo, as the developing languages that unity IDE offers.

In my game I need to store the game state : user name, level, game moves, current state, points and all the things that should be save. 
I want to enable the user to save the game in some certain time, and lets say that after 
couple of hours, when he wants to continue the game, he will be able to load the game from the point he stopped.

So I know that maybe I need 2 tables, one for the user data, and the other table for each game
 - to save the game state..

but I want to know if there is any option to add a local DB to Unity?

I saw this [tutorial](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-save-and-load-your-players-progress-in-unity--cms-20934) which describes how to serialize object in order to save the game state.. but I don't know if this will answer my game needs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can look at [this unity answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/130716/local-database-method.html) for some help with using sqlite.

However in most situations i would use serialization instead of a local database.

The advantage of a database is thats you can easily search your data.

The advantage of serialization is that you can make your class structure the way you want it and the just save/load it without any need for adapters and parsing.

I would use a database if i had a lot of data, like thousands of rows. Or if my data has complex relations, ie lots of tables with relations between them. Otherwise i think its easier and less work to use serialization.

Comment: I see, what I want to save is the game state.
You see, my game is 3d tetris, and lets say that if you play the game and after 15 minutes you need to do something more important than playing, you would probably want to save the game, the moves, the objects positions, the points, the date, the level, under a given name right? so this is the data I need to store or save, I think that serialization would be a good way for this, but the problem is that it somehow need to be connected to the "player data" no? And SQLITE isn't free.. I don't want to pay a lot of money to one project..

Comment: What is this "player data" and how is it stored? Also most database servers do cost or require extra setup outside of your unity game which might be troublesome for you.

Comment: I was thinking about to have 2 tables, one table to store the player data: name, game_date, current_points, game_num 
and the other table will be game_moves, objects_position. 
so if I click "load game" it will show me list of players who saved their games, when I choose some player, I get all his saved games.. and then load it

Comment: If you want that behavior with serialization you make a class PlayerData which has a list of GameSave. If you dont want do load all the saves every time you can serialize them as separate files and place them folders for each of your PlayerData. Say player Elior has three saves. Then you have one file called Elior.sav and a folder called Elior and in that folder you have three files, one for each save.

Comment: plus one for talking about the serialization possibility. You should also move your example directly in your answer, it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Please go here for a solution which worked for me: https://medium.com/@rizasif92/sqlite-and-unity-how-to-do-it-right-31991712190

Which references and includes this GitHub sqllite-unity-plugin: https://github.com/rizasif/sqlite-unity-plugin

The code used looks like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Data;
using Mono.Data.Sqlite;
using System.IO;

public class SqliteTest : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        // Create database
        string connection = "URI=file:" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "My_Database";

        // Open connection
        IDbConnection dbcon = new SqliteConnection(connection);
        dbcon.Open();

        // Create table
        IDbCommand dbcmd;
        dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
        string q_createTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, val INTEGER )";

        dbcmd.CommandText = q_createTable;
        dbcmd.ExecuteReader();

        // Insert values in table
        IDbCommand cmnd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
        cmnd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO my_table (id, val) VALUES (0, 5)";
        cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // Read and print all values in table
        IDbCommand cmnd_read = dbcon.CreateCommand();
        IDataReader reader;
        string query ="SELECT * FROM my_table";
        cmnd_read.CommandText = query;
        reader = cmnd_read.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Debug.Log("id: " + reader[0].ToString());
            Debug.Log("val: " + reader[1].ToString());
        }

        // Close connection
        dbcon.Close();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```